# /sys/class/gpio values only working if python gpio script was used before

Tags: gpio, python

i have a problem with the gpio sysfs files.
when i use `cat` to get the values of a gpio pin it will always show `0`.
but after using a python script ( https://github.com/elParaguayo/RPI-Info-Screen/blob/PiTFT/pitftgpio.py ) the pins work normally.

im using the normal commands to adress the gpio:
    `sudo sh -c 'echo 23 > /sys/class/gpio/export'` , setting direction
    and then `cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value`

Comment: What are you doing to the gpio to make it change value?  All the Python code seems to do is open gpio 23 as an input and set a pull-up to 3V3.

Comment: Maybe something like 'echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction' to specify pin23 as an input, I'm not sure how to set the pullup.

Comment: thanks, i think its the pull-up. i set the direction,but forgot to mention it ;)

Comment: is it necessesary to set the pull-up?

Comment: It depends on what is connected to the gpio.  If nothing is connected it will float randomly between 0 and 1.  The pull-up will fix the gpio high unless an external circuit pulls it low.

Comment: Use something better. Wiring pi and gpio utility are set up for non-root.